# How compareTo method works?

Tags: java, compareto

Emp class is having two fields `int id, int salary` implements `Comparable<Emp>`. Here I'm giving only the compareTo logic:

```
public int compareTo(Emp e) {
    if(this.salary<e.salary) {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return -1;
    }
}
```

In the main I've

```
Emp e1=new Emp(1,200);
Emp e2=new Emp(2,300);
Emp e3=new Emp(3,400);
Emp e4=new Emp(4,50);

ArrayList<Emp> ar=new ArrayList<>();
ar.add(e1);
ar.add(e2);
ar.add(e3);
ar.add(e4);
Collections.sort(ar);
for(Emp e:ar)
    System.out.println(e);
```

Now my question is compareTo() method is working correctly? 
In the method

```
list 1(200) is compared with list 2(300) and swapped
list 1(300) is compared with list 2 list 3(400) and swapped
```

in this way I'm getting 400 200 300 50 but I'm getting result correctly please tell me how it is working internally?

Comment: what if `this.salary == e.salary`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: must return 0 if equal, 1 if greater and -1 is lesser but I'm focused how it is working internally

Comment: `Now my question is in compareTo() method is working correctly?` answer is no

Comment: yes I'm getting correct result

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List) `This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays`

Comment: *I'm getting 400 200 300 50 but I'm getting result correctly* - if it's supposed to be sorted it doesn't seem to be correct, does it?

Comment: your code produces code since you use `Collections.sort(ar)`

Comment: your code does not produce `400 200 300 50`

Comment: your code looks working to you only because you're not testing edge cases, all your values in array are different, add multiple objects with the same salary into array at different positions and you will find when your code does not work

Comment: Ilya Bursov  so intrnally it implements merge sort and I just have to specify whther I want increasing or decreasing order right?

Comment: @MYPC you just have to specify comparator or implement Comparable, which will ultimately decide order

Answer (score 2):

in case `this.salary==e.salary` your method will not work properly , change your method to this

```
public int compareTo(Emp e) {
        if(this.salary==e.salary)
            return 0;
        else if(this.salary<e.salary)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an issue with your Comparator:

From java official doc:

> `int compareTo(T o)`
>
> **Parameters**:
> `o` - the object to be compared.
>
> **Returns:**
> a negative integer, **zero**, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
>
> **Throws:**
> `NullPointerException` - if the specified object is null
> `ClassCastException` - if the specified object's type prevents it from being compared to this object.

You should also implement the case when objects are equal on the comparison criteria, in this case your `compareTo(T o)` should **return 0**.

**Sorting code:**

```
Emp e1=new Emp(1,200);
Emp e2=new Emp(2,300);
Emp e3=new Emp(3,400);
Emp e4=new Emp(4,50);

List<Emp> ar= new ArrayList<Emp>();

ar.add(e1);
ar.add(e2);
ar.add(e3);
ar.add(e4);

Collections.sort(ar, new Comparator<Emp>(){
     @Override
     public int compare(Emp e1, Emp e2)
     {

         return  e1.compareTo(e2);
     }
});

for(Emp e:ar)
    System.out.println(e);
```

**Emp class:**

```
...

public int compareTo(Emp e) {
    //ascending order
    if(this.salary==e.getSalary())
        return 0;
    else if(this.salary<e.getSalary())
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Make it more fun by making it a nested ternary.

Comment: There is no `Comparator` here.

Comment: don't use subtraction to produce `compareTo` result, what if `e.getSalary()` is `Integer.MIN_INT`?